# Bottom Justify Shiny Elements

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have an app set up as this is. As the user selects multiple items from the **Animals** dropdown, the printout of what they have selected gets longer and pushes the elements under it down

I would like for the elements under it to be justified to the bottom of the page so that they don't move as more animals are selected

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# Define UI for app
ui <- 
  
  fillPage(
    
    column(2,
           
           fluidRow(
             # Input 1: animal
             selectInput(
               inputId = 'FilterFieldSelection',
               label = 'Animal Of Choice',
               choices = c('Dog','Cat','Inu','Neko','Giraffe','Kirin','Mouse','Nezumi'),
               selected = 'Dog',
               multiple = TRUE
             ), 
             
             
             # Output 1: Active Filters
             htmlOutput('ActiveFiltersText')
             
           ),
           
           fluidRow(
             
             h4("Counts"),
             
             # Input 2: color
             selectInput(
               inputId = 'ColorChoice',
               label = 'Color Of Choice',
               choices = c('red','blue','green'),
               selected = 'red'
             ), 
             
             # Output 2: Filtered Well Count
             htmlOutput('WellCountFilteredText'),
           )
    ),
    
    column(10,
           
           plotOutput('myplot')
           
    )
  )

# Define Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Text Outputs ----
  ## Text Output Of Active Filters ----
  output$ActiveFiltersText <- renderUI({
    
    full_text <- ""
    
      
        
        full_text <- paste0(full_text, '<b>','There Is A','</b>:<br/>',
                            paste(input$FilterFieldSelection,collapse="<br/>"),'<br/>'
        )
        
    full_text <- HTML(full_text)
  })
  
  
  ## Text Output Of Filtered Well Count ----
  output$WellCountFilteredText <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste0('<b>','Filtered','</b>:<br/>',150000))
  })

  ## Plot
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    m <- matrix(rnorm(50), ncol = 5)
    colnames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
    as_tibble(m) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b) ) +
      geom_point(color=input$ColorChoice)
  })
}

# Run App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried putting the elements to not move in another fluidRow, but that didn't change anything. They're still fully top-justified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the elements in a `div` with CSS style properties `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2, 
      
      selectInput(
        inputId = 'FilterFieldSelection',
        label = 'Animal Of Choice',
        choices = c('Dog','Cat','Inu','Neko','Giraffe','Kirin','Mouse','Nezumi'),
        selected = 'Dog',
        multiple = TRUE
      ), 
      
      tags$div(
        style = "position: fixed; bottom: 0;",
        
        # Output 1: Active Filters
        htmlOutput('ActiveFiltersText'),
        
        tags$hr(),
        
        h4("Counts"),
        
        # Input 2: color
        selectInput(
          inputId = 'ColorChoice',
          label = 'Color Of Choice',
          choices = c('red','blue','green'),
          selected = 'red'
        ), 
        
        # Output 2: Filtered Well Count
        htmlOutput('WellCountFilteredText'),
      )
    ),
    
    column(
      10, 
      plotOutput("myplot")
    )
  )
)
```